# ElasticSearch terms aggregation over a substring

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, substring, elasticsearch-aggregation

I want to do a terms aggregation of a zipCode - once with 5 digits and once with 3 digits (germany).

5 digits is a normal terms aggregation.

For 3 digits I'm trying the following script:

```
terms.script={
                "source": "def zipCode = doc['zip.keyword'].size() > 0 ? doc['zip.keyword'].substring(0,2) : ''; return zipCode",
                "lang": "painless",
            }
```

That throws me following error:

```
root_cause: [
    {
      type: 'script_exception',
      reason: 'runtime error',
      script_stack: [Array],
      script: "def zipCode = doc['zip.keyword'].size() > 0 ? " +
        "doc['zip.keyword'].substring(0,2) : ''; return " +
        'zipCode',
      lang: 'painless'
    }
  ],
```

The mapping of the field:

```
  zip: {
            type: "text",
            fields: {
                keyword: {
                    type: "keyword",
                    ignore_above: 256
                }
             }
          }
```

Using ElasticSearch 7.6.

So how can I make this terms aggregation with scripted field work? :)

Important to say - sometimes the field is null or not existent.

Answer (score 0):

You've gotta call `.value` on the keyword when you intend to perform string ops on it:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "zipcodes": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "source": """
          def zipCode = doc['zip.keyword'].size() > 0
              ? doc['zip.keyword'].value.substring(0, 2)
              : '';
          return zipCode
          """,
          "lang": "painless"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you paste my code from above or did you adjust your original code?

Comment: BTW you can jump into the script and call `Debug.explain(whatever)` to investigate what's-what: https://prnt.sc/re49dk vs https://prnt.sc/re49vb

Comment: I did not paste it - I will now

Comment: I pasted it - at least in IntelliJ this """ gives me an error - sorry if I'm newbie. Otherwise same error

Comment: Also, and this is not a solution to this specific problem, but I would consider just indexing the short version as well - the space requirements are probably gonna be minimal, and I find it to be alot cleaner (and faster) than script aggregations

Comment: @StefanoBranco is right in that scripts tend to be less clean and are guaranteed to run more slowly. @Fabian it's still not exactly clear what your error is from your `runtime_error`. Try to run it in Kibana first. Also, it's good practice to safeguard against accessing doc fields that may not be there. So the best thing to do would be `"source": "if (!doc.containsKey('zip')) { return ''; } def zipCode = doc['zip.keyword'].size() > 0 ? doc['zip.keyword'].value.substring(0, 2) : ''; return zipCode"`

Comment: @StefanoBranco you are probably right - scripting is kind of a pain anyway tbh... At least for testing purpose now it would be great if it works - later on I can index it. Will try it with kibana now